# How do I combine undefined with booleans in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example suppose I have

```
var myVar;
```

If I do

```
console.log((myVar != undefined) && true);
```

It returns false as expected.  Is it possible to do something closer to

```
console.log(myVar && true);
```

It's much less verbose.  At the moment the above returns undefined I would like false.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `&& true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to turn `undefined` and `false` into `false` and `true` into `true`. If so, this should work fine:

```
console.log(!!myVar);
```

Each `!` converts the value to a boolean and returns the opposite. The opposite of the opposite is the same as the original, except for that "converts to a boolean" part, which is exactly what you want.

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929).

Answer (score 2):

One way to drag a boolean out of a "truthy" or "falsy" value is to use `!!`

```
console.log(!!myVar);
```